# Algorithm for finding reference angle

Tags: c++, algorithm, trigonometry, angle

Definition of "reference angle":

> An angle ϑ<sub>r</sub> in the interval [0, 2π) corresponding to an angle ϑ outside of this interval, satisfying the conditions
>   sin(ϑ) = sin(ϑ<sub>r</sub>) and cos(ϑ) = cos(ϑ<sub>r</sub>).

For example (thinking in degrees for simplicity):

> ref(390<sup>o</sup>) = 30<sup>o</sup>
>   ref(360<sup>o</sup>) = 0<sup>o</sup>
>   ref(-40<sup>o</sup>) = 320<sup>o</sup>
>   ref(540<sup>o</sup>) = 180<sup>o</sup>

An example code for finding reference angle is:

```
double FindReferenceAngle(double Angle)
{
    const double TWOPI = 2.0 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    while(true)
    {
        if (Angle >= TWOPI)
        {
            Angle -= TWOPI;
        }
        else if (Angle < 0)
        {
            Angle += TWOPI;
        }
        else
        {
            return Angle;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't think that this code is optimal. For instance, if the user calls it with a very large angle value (e.g.; `FindReferenceAngle(1e10)`) it will take quite a time in the while loop.

Is there any other more efficient algorithm to find reference angle, like a built in standard C++ library routine?

Comment: You are doing it in degrees first, but your code is in radians. If you stick to degrees, you just need a%360, if radians you can count in multiples of pi and so have a%2*pi or fmod if you really want floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
double FindReferenceAngle(double Angle)
{
    const double TWOPI = 2.0 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    return fmod(Angle, TWOPI);
}
```

Though it would probably be a good idea to globalize the definition of pi and put it in a header somewhere, or perhaps this:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#ifdef M_PI
#define TWOPI 2*M_PI
#else
#define TWOPI 2.0*3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Matt Phillips's answer is a valid and proper solution.
I want to add another solution in which operation of the `fmod` function is explicitly implemented.

```
double FindReferenceAngle(double Angle)
{
    const double TWOPI = 2.0 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    if (Angle >= 0)
    {
        return Angle - TWOPI * floor(Angle / TWOPI);
    }
    else
    {
        return Angle - TWOPI * ceil(Angle / TWOPI);
    }
}
```